Why aren't all people with warrants arrested notified immediately
Suppose that a warrant is issued to person X. It may take time to locate that person and then maybe two officers are needed to make the arrest. As a result, it is not practical to arrest somebody right away because an arrest warrant has been issued.
It seems to me that if a person has an arrest warrant issued, the police should notify that person by a phone call right away. However, they often do not. Why not?

Arrest is a measure intended to prevent obstruction of justice through destruction of evidence, witness tampering, and/or flight, and to ensure the arrestee shows up in court.
Informing the arrestee in a criminal case of the warrant before the arrest could have been made may potentially defeat the purpose.
In some cases, where it does make sense, this happens. Usually when the person is expected and intends to surrender themselves, and forceful detention is not needed. Donald Trump, for example, wasn't forcefully detained but instead surrendered himself in all the jurisdictions where he's under arrest.
In more mundane cases like traffic cases, a person can actually look up if there's an arrest warrant against them (e.g.: See here), and get instructions on what to do about it. In these cases no-one is going to be actively looking for the person or sending officers, but if officers run into them (in another traffic stop, for example), they'll execute the warrant.
